# Artifactory Enforcement of Standards for Deployed Artifacts

Tags: artifactory

Can Artifactory enforce the types of artifacts that are deployed to it?

Even better on a per-repository basis?

For example, if I want to deploy a tar.gz to repository x then it has to be 3-digit versioned

i.e. I can deploy 13.02.01.tar.gz but not 13.02.tar.gz

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 3):

While this is not supported out of the box, your goal can be achieved via the [User-Plugins](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) extension mechanism. 
You can take a look [here](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins), [here](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/layouts/layoutEnforcement), and [here](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/governance), for some ideas on how to achieve your goal.